# D3.js read csv file with special characters, é à ü è

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, character-encoding

Best

I've a small question.
How do you read in, csv-files which contain special characters without having words like ***?l?ve*** (élève) etc.

at this moment i'm using :

```
d3.csv("xml/info.csv", function(data) {
  for (obj in data) {
                console.log(data[obj].name.toLowerCase())   
   }
}
```

+ my html contains the next sentence in the header

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Kind regards

Comment: is the file saved in utf8? and does it work when you open the file with a text editor?

Comment: @RolandStarke - If i open the csv in notepad++ everything is okey

Comment: @RolandStarke - no it didn't, and i converted it to UTF-8 And now it works, but it doesn't solve my initial problem :) because i've more then 1 csv file :) - but i can change all the other files ...

Answer (score 4):

In D3.js you can configure your [asynchronous request function](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Requests.md) in several ways. For Comma-separated or Delimiter-separated variables (CSV/DSV) you can configure the delimiter and Mime Type of your data using [d3.dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md#arbitrary-delimiters).

So, in case it's not practicable to convert all your files to UTF-8, you could load them as ISO-8859-1 (or some other encoding) by first configuring the loading function (which also allows you to change the delimiter):

```
var loadDsv = d3.dsv(",", "iso-8859-1");
```

Then you can load your file in that encoding:

```
loadDsv("xml/info.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

If you need more control over your async loading, you can also use [d3.xhr](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Requests.md) where you can configure any Ajax parameters you wish.